# Multicolumn table header alignment

Tags: tables, multicolumn

I'm trying to align multicolumn table headers in order to achieve the following result:
[image]

However this is what I was able to achieve by nesting \thead inside \multicolumn:
[image]

Note how the desired table header fully spans the 2 columns, as opposed to my case where it looks shrinked.
This is the tex itself:

```
\begin{table*}[th]
\centering
\par%
\begin{tabular}
[c]{cccccccc}\hline
Method & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\thead{NOT YOS \\\hline LIB}} &
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\thead{LIB YOS \\\hline NOT}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\thead{LIB NOT \\\hline YOS}} & Mean\\\hline
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}

\begin{table*}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{cccccccc}
\toprule
\multirow{2.4}{*}{Method} & NOT & YOS & LIB & YOS & LIB & YOT & \multirow{2.4}{*}{Mean}\\
\cmidrule(r){2-3} \cmidrule(lr){4-5} \cmidrule(l){6-7}
 & \multicolumn{2}{c}{LIB} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{NOT} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{YOS} & \\
\midrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table*}
\end{document}
```